# Change in current on adding a resistor

Tags: homework-and-exercises, electric-circuits, electric-current, charge, electrical-resistance

> Is it correct to say that the current flowing through a given resistor remains constant even if another resistor is connected in parallel with it, assuming a source of constant EMF and no other components in the circuit?

My attempt:
Consider two resistor of resistances $R_1$ and $R_2$.
Initially, $I = \frac V{R_1}$

After connecting, let $I$ be the total current and $I_1$ and $I_2$ the currents through the individual resistances.

$I = \frac {V(R_1 + R_2)}{R_1R_2}$

$I_1 = \frac{IR_2}{R_1 + R_2} = \frac{V}{R_1}$

Somehow this dosen't seem correct to me.

Comment: Think of the voltage $V$ over the resistor. Does that change when another one is added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it correct to say that the current flowing through a given resistor
>   remains constant even if another resistor is connected in parallel
>   with it, assuming a source of constant EMF and no other components in
>   the circuit?

Yes and you've showed that using KCL and then current division.  But, as a comment points out, the result follows simply from your problem statement.

(1) the resistors are connected in parallel which *means* they have the same voltage across

(2) there is a voltage source across the parallel resistors and no other components in the circuit so the voltage across either resistor is $V$, the terminal voltage of the voltage source

(3) the voltage produced by the voltage source is *constant*

That's really all there is to it.  Since the terminal voltage of the voltage source is constant, adding yet another resistor in parallel does not change $V$;  $V$ is independent of the total current.

By Ohm's law, the current through the resistor is the voltage across divided by the resistance.

Thus,

$$I_n = \frac{V}{R_n},\qquad V\; \mathrm{constant}$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are correct in saying that "In the given situation, current flowing through a given resistor remains constant even if another resistor is connected in parallel with it". Because Ohm's Law says that current through a resistor depends only on the voltage across itself and its own resistance. When you have connected two resistors in parallel with a constant EMF source of potential difference V, then voltage across each resistor is V and so by Ohm's Law individual currents will be V/R1 and V/R2. When you remove R2 from the circuit, still the potential difference across R1 is V, hence by Ohm's Law current through it will be V/R1. But notice that total current changes when you remove or add a parallel resistor. Emf source has to provide the current to all the resistors. The power delivered by the EMF source also changes when you add or remove a parallel resistor.